# Phone activity from android wear app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, wear-os

Like the Header says. Is it possible to get the current phone activity (or layout) from an app on the wear? I don't know how-to do that, so I didn't use any method and every advice will be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AccessibilityService to read the current Window open on the phone through AccessibilityEvents and AccessibilityNodeInfo objects. Check out this training tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html